# Select a valid combination of adults and children for a room

Tags: java, data-structures, backtracking

My problem is,

For example,

Number of adults = 4

Number of children = 3

There are two rooms.

Each room has min Adults and max adults limit and min Children and max children limit. I need to book the two rooms with a valid combination of adults and children in each room, there may be number of valid combinations but once I get a valid combination, I am done.

For example,

> room1 minimum adults = 2 and max adults = 3
>
> room1 minimum children = 1 and max children = 1
>
> room2 minimum adults = 1 and max adults = 1
>
> room2 minimum children = 1 and max children = 2

I have divided number of adults as following groups
Set 1: [4, 0][0, 4][1, 3][3, 1][2, 2]

I have divided number of children as following groups
Set 2: [3, 0][0, 3][1, 2][2, 1]

Example for a valid combination is 3 adults and 1 child in room 1 and 1 adult and 2 children in room2.

I need to implement this in Java. I have no idea on how to solve this and what Data structure to use and what programming technique.

Comment: Just try to satisfy the min requirement first, then fill in the rest to the max of each room.

Answer (score 1):

First you create a class Range allowing you to specify a minimum and maximum.
Next you create a class Room having 2 ranges.
Next you create a class RoomOccupation with 2 attributes: nr of adults and nr of children.
Next you add a method to the Room class spawning back a Set containing all allowed combinations.

Next comes the tricky part: you loop over the 2 sets of possible occupations of both rooms, add the nr adults of each occupation into a total and match this to the number of people needing a room. if all totals match => bingo. The tricky part is that this is easily programmed in 2 for loops as you have 2 rooms. If you want to make your program independant of the number of rooms you have to eliminate this double for loop and use recursion. Instead you could create a List>. A recursive method would use a parameter index to loop over this list.get(index). If index == list.size-1 and number of totals match -> bingo else call the method recursively with index+1 as parameter.

Comment: Can you please provide me a small snippet for what you mentioned in second part of second paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Room{
public int roomNumber;
public int minAdults;
public int maxAdults;
public int minChildren;
public int maxChildren;
public int numAdultsInRoom;
public int numChildrenInRoom;

public Room(int number){
this.roomNumber = number;

switch (number){
case 1:
{
minAdults = 2;
maxAdults = 3;
minChildren = 1;
maxChildren = 1;

}//case1
break;

case 2:
{
minAdults = 1;
maxAdults = 1;
minChildren = 1;
maxChildren = 2;

}//case2
break;
}//switch

numAdultsInRoom = 0;
numChildrenInRoom = 0;
}//room

}//room class
```

when getting new input

```
HashMap<Integer,Room> roomsMap = new HashMap<Integer,Room>();

roomsMap.put(1,new Room(1));
roomsMap.put(2,new Room(2));
```

entering people in room

```
if room is 1, and person is child
   if (maxchildren in room> children in room){
childrenInRoom++;
}
```

and so on

upon edits : Room r = roomsMap.get(roomNumber);
edit r, put back r

Comment: The author of the question seems to be a learner. I believe that it would be a better help for them when you would explain how the solution works, not provide them with a finished solution.